# Java ExecuteUpdate method for prepared statement hangs

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

So I've been working on trying to get a certain prepared statement to work to insert values into my database. For reference I'm using MySQL server 5.5 and Connector/J as my database + driver.

I try to run the following code:

```
     sql = "INSERT INTO event "
+ "( ename, description, edatetime, location, is_public_e,sponsored_by)"+"VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?);";                          
                        PreparedStatement a1 = con.prepareStatement(sql);                                           
                        a1.setString(1, ename.toString());
                        a1.setString(2, desc.toString());
                        a1.setString(3, date);
                        a1.setString(4, location.toString());
                        a1.setInt(5, pub);
                        a1.setString(6, clubid.toString());
                        a1.executeUpdate();
```

Where ename, description and location are strings, edatetime is a datetime, is_public is a boolean and sponsored_by is an integer. No matter what data I use running this code through eclipse will result in an indefinite hang on the executeUpdate() line.

Using the same data, however, I can insert the event through the server command line. Stranger still is that other insert statements work flawlessly. I thought the problem may be the datetime conversion but hardcoding the datetime cast into the statement still resulted in a hang.

Could anyone give any insight into why this is happening?

Right now my only thoughts are that it is my server +  driver configuration, but I redownloaded the software on my laptop and the problem persisted so I don't believe it is an issue. I also assume there is no limit to wildcards I can use in a prepared statement, but if there is could that cause the problem? Additionally earlier in the code I set the  connection to autocommit but I am unsure as to whether my driver supports that, and given the fact that my other inserts work I am unsure if that is the issue.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It hangs indefinitely, and you don't get any error? Try to run in debug mode and see what's happening: is it really the database code that's hanging. It could happen that a database lock is causing an insert to hang. Make sure previous statements (insert, updates, reads) are properly closed.

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the code you are showing us. Can we see more?

Comment: @OP: If you use a `Statement` instead of `PreparedStatement` how is the behaviour, in this particular insert?

Comment: Statements give the same behavior in this case. I'll add some more code when I get home later today. Also there is no error, it just sticks on that line, and even when I have that be the first insert to execute it still hangs, so I don't believe there should be a lock, but I'll check when I get home.

Answer (score 1):

So I resolved the problem by preparing my statement with:

```
a1.setString(1, ename);
a1.setString(2, desc);
a1.setString(3, date + " " + time);
a1.setString(4, location);
a1.setInt(5, 1);
a1.setInt(6, cid);
```

I think this was fixed by reformatting the datetime into yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format and I think this was being formatted and not throwing an sqlException correctly.

Comment: Why not use setDate to store date/time information in the database? You should let the database make its own decisions about how it should be stored

Answer (score -1):

Try `ps.executeQuery()` instead of `ps.executeUpdate()`. It worked in my case.

EDIT: Pardon for my previous answer.

Comment: `executeQuery()` returns a `ResultSet` and better for `select` queries.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()

Comment: You would receive an error with message `SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()`